# log4net add AssemblyVersion to appender filename

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm trying to figureout how to add AssemblyVersion number to a log4net appender. With that I mean..

```
<appender name="RollingFile" ..> 
   <file value="{TEMP}\MyApp\<AssemblyVersion>\MyApp.log"/>
   ..
</appender>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. 
See "[Dynamic log fileNames with log4net](http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/dynamic-log-filenames-with-log4net.aspx)"

```xml
<appender name="RollingFileAppenderV1" 
          type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
        value="F:\HornetFeed\%property{LogName}" />
```

Then in C# code:

```cs
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = "file1.log";
```